# Change `wp db export` default database name

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Is there a way to change what the database is named when using the `wp db export` command?

When I type `wp db export` on one of my WordPress sites, the database gets named `{dbname}-{Y-m-d}-{random-hash}.sql`, which is correct according to [WP-CLI Commands](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/export/). When I run the same command on one of my other sites, it names the db `dbname.sql` (which I prefer).

Is there a way I can have `wp db export` name the exported db `dbname.sql`?

I know I can type `wp db export dbname.sql` but I just wanted to see if the default when typing `wp db export` could be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using different versions of WP-CLI on both machines. Up until version [1.2.0](https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/blob/5c597abb642bcaf329e7da0801c69f4405d41c23/src/DB_Command.php#L260) the default was just `{dbname}.sql`. Since version [1.2.1](https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/blob/db37442ae6e3a6bc91274d751d188eed4873e910/src/DB_Command.php#L261) it defaults to `{dbname}-{Y-m-d}-{random-hash}.sql`.

Verify the WP-CLI versions with

```
wp --version
```

There is no way to override the default itself other than you just did by passing it a filename. But there still is a way to get the database name dynamically and then name the file after it by using the `--porcelain` option to only get the filename and then chain two `wp db export` commands together like that:

```
# Exports the database named '{dbname}.sql'.
wp db export $(wp db export --porcelain | cut -f1 -d "-").sql
```

`cut -f1 -d "-"` cuts the porcelain output with the first `-`. Since databases can't have dashes in their name, this seems a pretty save method to be used on your system with the newer WP-CLI version.

---

To have one command to be used on both your machines, you may need to find a way to check for the existence of `-` characters first, and cut only if a `-` exists. Or install a WP-CLI lower than version 1.2.1 on both machines.